# Download picture from internet with a batch script

Tags: windows, html, css

I try to download picture through a batch script

```
:downloadPicture

bitsadmin /transfer downloadPicture  /download /priority normal  http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/nature-wallpaper-download-20.jpg  C:\Users\%username%\desktop\%pictureName%
```

It's going on giving me an error telling that the server does not support the necessary HTTP protocol.

By the way, this is just part of the project. I set pictureName somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For me the code is working fine (i test it on my computer)

You can also use curl ou wget to do the same job. For exemple with wget:

```
powershell.exe -Command wget <file_url> -OutFile <file_name>
```

You can get wget for windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).